# How to reference custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a custom `textBox` and a custom `Button`. I have a click event for my button so that when the button is clicked,the `textBox` entry is stored as an int value.

I have done this like so:

```
    //Save item button
    Button saveItem = new Button();
    saveItem.Size = new Size(135,23);
    saveItem.Location = new Point(20, 169);
    saveItem.Text = "Save to items";
    saveItem.Name = "saveItem";
    Controls.Add(saveItem);
    // Add a Button Click Event handler
    saveItem.Click += new EventHandler(saveItem_Click);
}


private void saveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    itemBuy1 = Int32.Parse(buyPrice.Text); //buyPrice is the custom textBox I created 
}
```

When I try do this,I get an red error line under `buyPrice.Text` with the error message "The name buyPrice does not exist in the current context."

The textBox is definitely called "buyPrice",I have not made a typo or anything. The label buyPrice was created upon a button being clicked.

buyPrice is declared like so: (hope this makes it clearer)

```
 private void itemToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox buyPrice = new TextBox();
        buyPrice.Size = new Size(100,20); 
        buyPrice.Location = new Point(65,86);
        buyPrice.Name = "buyPrice";
        Controls.Add(buyPrice);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare `buyPrice`?

Comment: I declare buy price inside a private button onClick eventargs.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: This is a c# windows form

Comment: In the future, please supply this sort of information in the tags.

Comment: When you declare an object inside a method it's private to that method.  Declare it at class level and assign the values you want inside the method.  Or, since you're adding it to the Controls collection, you can try accessing through that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference of your custom control(need to add reference if seperate project and need to include Namespace with the help of using statement like other system and third party controls are integrated.) into your xaml.cs and your (hope your custom control has inherited Textbox class).

Comment: How do I add the reference to my XAML.cs?

Comment: by using  statement and namespace will be your usercontrol's namespace.